# DocuSign using REST API to set Signing Group as a recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send an envelope with a recipient being a Signing Group using the REST API.

Here is example XML code that I POST:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>xxxxxx</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <emailSubject>xxxxxxxxxxx</emailSubject>
   <templateId>xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx</templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <templateRole>
         <name>Test Signing Group</name>
         <roleName>Test Role Name</roleName>
      </templateRole>
      <templateRole>
         <name>Non Signing Group</name>
         <roleName>Standard Role</roleName>
         <email>test@example.com</email>
      </templateRole>
   </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

So for Template Role #1 I am trying to assign Test Signing Group to Test Role Name and for Template Role #2 I am able to assign the Standard Role to Non Signing Group with the email being test@example.com. Because I excluded the email for Template Role #1 I get an error message of "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows."

I am wondering how am I suppose to assign the fields because a signing group is for multiple emails to possibly sign.

The reason I want to use the API to set the signing group as the recipient is because depending on variables I will change what signing group is assigned to Template Role #1 which is figured out in an earlier external process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the signingGroupId, then name/email@ does not become required. You will need to use the ID of the group not the name. You can query the signinGroupId's from the /accounts/{accountId}/signing_groups endpoint.

Sample update to envelope creation call:

```xml
  <templateRole>
     <signingGroupId>12345</signingGroupId>
     <roleName>Test Role Name</roleName>
  </templateRole>
```

[Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/list/) reference re: signingGroupId:

Comment: FYI it's a bit hidden but we do mention signingGroupID in this page of our documentation when specifying an envelope recipient: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Recipients/Signers Recipient.htm?Highlight=signingGroupId

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't see the signingGroupId option when reading the Documentation.