# Is Docusign REST API supports signing group as a recipient?

Tags: api, docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

I have not found any documentation in DocuSign REST API to add a signing group as a  recipient.

There is a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888924/docusign-using-rest-api-to-set-signing-group-as-a-recipient), but it is not helpful for me.

I have a signing group and DocuSign creates a **signing group id**. I have not set an alternate email address for notifications sent to this signing group.

Is there any option to add a signing group as a recipient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `signingGroupId` attribute of the `signer` tab type.

For the Apex SDK it looks like there is a [Recipient.SigningGroup](https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/recipient.html) with attribute `id`